# Are Irrational Numbers also Rational Numbers?

Tags: infinity, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

I understand that irrational numbers are categorized by being numbers that continue infinitely. I guess my question is more precisely, are the infinite sets of irrational numbers considered rational numbers themselves? (Ex: {.30,.31,.32,.33,.34,.35,. . . . })

Comment: No.  Irrational numbers have non-repeating decimal expansions, while rational numbers eventually have repeating decimal expansions.

Comment: Also, a small grammar thing.  "i" in front of something means "not", so $$\text{irrational}=\text{not rational}$$

Comment: An irrational number by definition is one that is not rational

Comment: Also also, infinite sets of numbers are not numbers (under most definitions of 'number'). Under what circumstances would you think they would be?

Comment: The misconception you seem to have is that all numbers with an infinite decimal expansion is irrational. This is not true. For example $\frac{1}{3}=0.3333\ldots$ is rational.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: It did make me think of the Dedekind cut construction of the reals.  But that's almost the opposite of what the OP is looking for.

Comment: I don't see what the set $\{0.30,0.31,0.32,0.33,0.34,0.35,\ldots\}$ has to do with irrational numbers. It seems to be an arithmetic sequence counting up to infinity (although slowly). For example, the one-millionth member of the set (in the order you showed) is $10000.29.$ How do you think that example is relevant to your question? Perhaps it would be helpful if you would give as precise and explicit a description of how an irrational number can "continue indefinitely," as you understand it.

Comment: @all Thanks guys! All these explanations definitely taught me something and led me to make research in the right areas. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Rational numbers are numbers that can be written as a fraction $\frac ab$ with $a\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $b\in\mathbb{N}$. Irrational numbers are defined to be the opposite, numbers that *can't* be written that way.

To expand on this; it's (in my opinion) a bad custom to view numbers as "infinite digits behind a comma". Often, numbers don't even have a unique such representation.

Comment: Rational numbers is a fraction field of $\Zz$ , so $b\in \Zz$ too.

Comment: Well $b\neq 0$ and since we don't really need negative denominators (all they can do is cancel out the minus sign of $a$ or create one $a$ could've had) this suffices.

Comment: @MarussT: $\mathbb{Z}$ is '\mathbb{Z}'.

Comment: @Brian typed even easier as `\Bbb Z`

Answer (score 0):

No, sets of irrationals are not rational numbers, although provocatively, there is a construction of the reals called [Dedekind cuts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_cut), in which every real number (of which the overwhelming majority are irrational) is identified by a particular partition of the *rationals* into two subsets, with one subset $L$ containing all numbers below, and the other subset $R$ contains all numbers above, and $L$ not containing its *supremum*, or lowest upper bound.  (Equivalently, neither $L$ nor $R$ has a greatest element.)

Dedekind cuts have other applications, but this is the best known one.

---

To be sure, one could reverse the Dedekind cut and identify each rational number uniquely with the subset of irrational numbers that are less than that rational number.  However, I would hesitate to call that subset *an actual rational number*, since no one constructs rational numbers that way; it would be begging the question (circular reasoning).

Comment: As interesting as this is, considering that the OP asked if rational numbers were irrational, I don't think this is something the OP was looking for ;)

Comment: @vrugtehagel: Well, that's the way the title reads, but in the body of the question, the OP asks whether *sets* of irrational numbers are rational.  I thought it was interesting that the reverse is sometimes conceived of as true.

Comment: That's true, and even if the OP wasn't looking for it, it might still help future users looking for the thing you're explaining.

Answer (score 0):

The rational numbers, in decimal representation, have a finite or a infinite **and periodic** sequence of decimals (indeed we can say that a number with finite decimals have infinite zeros after, what is a periodic sequence after all).

In the other hand irrational numbers, in decimal representation, have an infinite sequence of decimals that is not periodic. This is the source of your confusion.

---

Just as a little curiosity (that would you surely surprise) is that

$$1.000000...=0.999999...$$

what imply that the decimal representation of numbers is not unique in many cases, by example

$$3.47=3.4699999...$$

Comment: Isn't it unique unless the number (a) has a terminating decimal representation; and (b) is not zero?  (a) is only true if the number has a rational representation in which the denominator is of the form $2^a5^b$, $a$ and $b$ non-negative integers.

Comment: @BrianTung yes, it is. Thanks I dont remembered this.